# dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler and assigning nil to @property ivar

Tags: iphone, ios5, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchertimer

When you have a cancel_handler for a timer, can you directly reference and reset any ivars declared as a property with 'assign' attribute or do you have to first assign it as a __block?

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject { }
@property (nonatomic, assign) dispatch_source_t             timer;
@end

// Class implementation
@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize timer = _timer;
- (void)startTimer 
{
    dispatch_queue_t globalQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 
                                    0, 0, globalQ); 

    dispatch_time_t startWhen = dispatch_walltime(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 1);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(_timer, startWhen, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 5000ull);

    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_timer, ^{
        // timer's event handler    
    });

    // VERSION 1:
    // Is it okay to reference and assign self.timer to nil 
    // or does it have to be declared as __block as in VERSION 2?
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(_timer, ^{
        dispatch_release(_timer);                
        self.timer = nil;
    });


    // VERSION 2:
    __block myTimer = self.timer;
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(_timer, ^{
        dispatch_release(myTimer);        

        myTimer = nil;
    });

    dispatch_resume(_timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference ivars just fine. However, these references carry an implicit reference to `self`, so you need to be wary of retain cycles. For example, if you reference an ivar directly, don't expect to shut down the timer in `-dealloc` because that will never be called.